# android rotated TextView inherits the parent's width

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I want to rotate a TextView -90 or 270 degrees and have the resulted overall width equal to the TextView height. Here is my mockup:

[image]

I make my TextView `120dp x 20dp`.

I insert it in a parent container (RelativeLayout or any).

I rotate it in XML with -90 degrees but then, when I set its parent to a `20dp` width the TextView inherits this width too so it clips my text (clipChildren set to false for the parent has no effect).

The TextView should be dynamic, it should be updated every time with the current month, I don't want to use background drawables for this.

Answer (score 3):

Well, after several hours of searching the web with no results or with people writing classes to do this and after only 30 minutes since posting the question I managed to achieve what I wanted.

I put my TextView in a FrameLayout and now it doesn't inherit its parent width. Also gave it a square proportion and a layout_gravity, here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:text="january"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:gravity="center|right"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:background="@color/itemMainBgColor"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Hell of a workaround!... Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Genius Logic .. Thumps up...